# Shuffling a greek word in iOS prints unknown symbols

Tags: ios, string, unicode

I want to shuffle a string that contains Greek characters:

Here is my code:

```
- (void)shuffle {
    NSLog(@"Will shuffle :%@",anagram2);

    NSData* data = [anagram2 dataUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"after encoding :%@",anagram2);

    NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Greek word:%@",someString);

    int length = anagram2.length;
    NSMutableArray *letters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i< length; i++) {
        NSString *letter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [someString characterAtIndex:i]]; 
        NSLog(@"Character:%@",letter);

        [letters addObject:someLetter];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
      int value = arc4random() % (length-1);
      //NSLog(@"Value is : %i", value);
      [letters exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:value];
    }
}
```

I can see the Greek word correctly. But the shuffling does not work. How can I extract each character and add it to a letters array. It works with English words but not with Greek ones, so I suppose that I should replace this:

```
NSString *letter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [someString characterAtIndex:i]];
```

with something else.

Comment: Why are you decoding and then reencoding the string data with the same character encoding? That seems pointless if all you want is a copy of the anagram string (which you shouldn't even need as you're copying all the characters into the mutable array anyway (which, by the way, you could pre-allocate with a size equal to the number of letters using `initWithCapacity:`. Might make things more efficient.)).

Comment: @JAB I did that back and forth for debugging. can you suggest me what should I call and where?

Comment: Another problem with the posted code - you derive `length` from `anagram2` but you extract characters from `someString`. Be sure to use the same string for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem seems to me that

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c":...]
```

works only with ASCII characters. You would have to use at least the `"%C"` format to make
it work with Unicode characters.

Also the conversion from `NSString` to `NSData` and back would fail as soon as you have any characters that are not available in the specified encoding.

The following method avoids all these problems and should work with arbitrary Unicode characters
(even with Emojis, which are internally represented as 2 UTF-16 characters):

```
NSString *string = @"Ελλάδα ";
NSLog(@"Will shuffle: %@", string);

// Convert string to an array of (32 bit) Unicode characters:
NSMutableData *data = [[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding] mutableCopy];
uint32_t *letters = [data mutableBytes];
int length = [data length]/4; // The number of 32-bit Unicode characters

// Shuffle the Unicode characters:
for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
    int value = arc4random() % (length-1);
    uint32_t tmp = letters[i];
    letters[i] = letters[value];
    letters[value] = tmp;
}

// Create new string from the shuffled Unicode characters:
NSString *shuffled = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Shuffled:     %@", shuffled);
```

Output:

```
Will shuffle: Ελλάδα 
Shuffled:     αάλλ Εδ
```

Comment: I am not sure if the shuffling algorithm (copied from your question) is 100% correct. I will update the answer if I find something ...

Comment: @rmaddy: If I understand the "inside-out" algorithm in ["Fisher–Yates shuffle"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle) correctly, `value` should be in the range 0 .. i (and not 0 .. length-1 as in the original code from this question).

Comment: My point was that you should use `arc4random_uniform(val)` instead of `arc4random() % val`.

Comment: @rmaddy: Yes, I understand, and thank you for the feedback! - I just noticed that there might be a general flaw in the shuffle algorithm as implemented by the OP.